# Unable to install opencv-python for Python 3.10 on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, installation, pip

I am trying to install opencv-python for Python 3.10 on a Mac so that I can use it for projects. I used the command `pip3.10 install opencv-python` However, I receive the following error message.

```
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
      Failed to build numpy
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I already have numpy installed. Do I need to uninstall numpy and try to install opencv-python?

Comment: Python 3.10 is still fresh version and some modules may not work for this version. Maybe better use 3.9

Comment: you may run `pip install` with option `-v` (lower `v` for `verbose`) to see more details . Maybe it needs to install some C/C++ libraries to compile some C/C++ code in numpy or opencv.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I decided to use Python 3.9 for the time being and installing opencv-python worked.